# Are Elflord and ElfQuest different?

Tags: comics, elves

So I was searching for another comic series (which sadly I don't think I found) and stumbled upon **Elflord**. I'm trying to find out if **Elflord** is connected to ElfQuest or if it is different, but I can't find more information beyond the fact that it was made by author/artist *Barry Blair* and I know that **ElfQuest** was made by a different author and artists. So I'm asking if it is connected to **ElfQuest**.

Comment: https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elfquest

Comment: https://recalledcomics.com/Elflord1.php

Comment: As Valorum has shown, *ElfQuest* and *Elflord* are indeed unrelated comics - except for the fact that Barry Blair also wrote and drew the *ElfQuest* spinoffs *New Blood* and *Blood of Ten Chiefs*

Comment: Ok thanks for clarification

Comment: This question is not closable without a formal answer.  It has been both answered and confirmed in the comments.  What do?

Comment: @DoscoJones -- Answer it :)  It's normally polite to let the person who provided the data (Valorum) answer it, and I usually give them a good bit of time (look at the user profile and see if they've been on lately) so I'm not basically stealing their answer, but nothing actually prevents you from posting an answer.

Comment: I'm not going to bogart someone else's answer.  There should be a close option for this use case.

Comment: @DoscoJones - It's not closeable, period. If you want to answer then go ahead :-)